# Как определить геолокацию mapkit?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пробую определить геолокацию так:

```
MapKit  mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance();
        mapKit.createLocationManager().subscribeForLocationUpdates(0,0, 0, true, FilteringMode.ON, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationUpdated(@NonNull Location location) {
                mapView.getMap().move(
                        new CameraPosition(location.getPosition(), 14.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                        new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                        null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationStatusUpdated(@NonNull LocationStatus locationStatus) {
            }
        });
```

Показывает Москву.

Comment: Не следует задавать вопросы по MapKit без контекста. Поскольку так непонятно, зачем вы пытаетесь уйти от данного Яндексом примера по отображению локации пользователя — https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/mapkit-demo/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/UserLocationActivity.java